# Selecting rows based on index positions, when the index positions are passed through variables in data.table R

Tags: r, variables, select, data.table

I can select one column by index position in data.table by passing the index position through a variable like this:

```
DT <- data.table(a = 1:6, b=10:15, c=20:25, d=30:35, e = 40:45)
i <- 1
j <- 5
DT[, ..i]
```

But how can I select columns i : i+2 and j in one line of code using data.table syntax?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `DT[,c(i,i+2,j),with=F]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [lukeA's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230933/selecting-rows-based-on-index-positions-when-the-index-positions-are-passed-thr#comment75471744_44230933) using the `with = FALSE` parameter you have other choices as well:

```
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = c(i:(i+2), j)]
#   a  b  c  e
#1: 1 10 20 40
#2: 2 11 21 41
#3: 3 12 22 42
#4: 4 13 23 43
#5: 5 14 24 44
#6: 6 15 25 45
```

Note the parantheses around `(i+2)` because the colon operator takes precendence.

This one is a modification of OP's code and not exactly a one-liner as requested:

```
icol <- c(i:(i+2), j); DT[, ..icol]
   a  b  c  e
1: 1 10 20 40
2: 2 11 21 41
3: 3 12 22 42
4: 4 13 23 43
5: 5 14 24 44
6: 6 15 25 45
```